# How to make Extent report (in Jenkins) show screenshot when a test fails?

Tags: jenkins, report

I'm having an issue where extent report is not showing the screenshot when a test fails and when accessing the report remotely via Jenkins url. But if the report is viewed on the same machine where Jenkins is installed, the screenshot is displayed. When saving the image into the report, I pass the absolute path of the image file. Is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it by using the following code (C#):

ExtentTest test;
test.AddScreenCapture("./screenshot.jpg");

Comment: Hey..How did you manage to display extentReport with proper formatting on Jenkins? I see only plain html without any css

Comment: Use "-Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP=" in the java command.

Refer "https://github.com/anshooarora/extentreports-java/issues/290" for more info.